# What is difference between add_definitions and set in CMake file

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, g++, gnu-make

I am new to CMake stuff. I got quite confused by `add_definitions` and `set` in CMake file.

For example, 
`add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` and `set(D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI,"0")`, is there any difference? I saw the different results but I cannot understand.

Second question: what does `D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` this do?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

`add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` appends `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` flag to every compiler invocation in the project.

`set(D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI,"0")` just sets CMake variable called `D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to `0`. You probably see no difference, because somewhere down the code it is used as value for `add_definitions()`:

```
if(D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI)
  add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=${D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI})
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think it is clear. So regarding to the second part, do you know what D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI actually changes?

Comment: I know this topic is a bit old. However the flag above indicates, if the compiler should enable the old ABI, or not. For details see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_dual_abi.html